# Zend_Validate_Between with ip2long

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I'm trying to validate an ip address using Zend_Validate_Between and i'm converting the ip to its long representation.

The issue is that I already have a validator that check for valid IPs 'Zend_Validate_Ip()'. Is there a way to use both ?

Thanks!

Comment: you can add multiple validators on a field using the addValidator() on the same field multiple times

Comment: just a question: why would you whant to use both ?

Comment: if you want to allow/restrict access to an IP range you will require both (one for the 0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255 and an other for for the 155.168.*.* for example)

Comment: I ended up writing a custom validator that would use Zend_Validate_Between and then attach it with addValidator() - Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm kind of guessing that what you're actually trying to do is validate whether or not an IP address is on a given subnet.  I'm writing a blog post on how to do that and will post it when I'm done.  If that's not what you're trying to do then that post will just be a freebie.  :-)

[Subnet validation with Zend Framework](http://bit.ly/hhtjA3)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that's sure a good read. I think it will be helpful because I'm dealing with something similar!